# How to change intensity of TikZ fading?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, reflection

I am attempting to do a mirror/reflection effect using TikZ fadings, but the fade that I am currently able to achieve is too 'gentle' - the line fades, but all of the line remains. The line's reflection itself is in the correct position, but the intensity of the fade is not enough - I want the line to disappear quite quickly.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
    paperwidth=17.78cm,
    paperheight=25.4cm,
    marginparsep=6.35mm,
    top=.5cm, % Top margin
    bottom=1cm, % Bottom margin
    left=2cm, % Left margin
    right=2cm, % Right margin
}

% Adds bleed
\usepackage[
width=18.0975cm,
height=26.035cm,
center,
%cam,
%cross,
%frame
]{crop}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \pagecolor{orange}\afterpage{\nopagecolor}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[overlay, white, line width=1.1mm] (-3,-.35) .. controls (-2.5,-4.5) and (5,-3.5) .. (20,.5);
        \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-6.15)},xscale=1,yscale=-1,rotate=360]
        \draw[overlay, white, line width=1.1mm,path fading=south] (-3,-.35) .. controls (-2.5,-4.5) and (5,-3.5) .. (20,.5);  % Mirror Image
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Which produces this:

[image: This is what I am currently able to achive using TikZ]

And this is the desired effect that I am trying to achieve:

[image: This is the desired effect (done in Pages)]

Is it possible to achieve my desired effect using TikZ?

Thank you very much for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can look up the definition of the original south fading in `pgflibraryfadings.code.tex` to find

```
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{pgf@lib@fade@south}{100bp}
{color(0bp)=(pgftransparent!100); color(25bp)=(pgftransparent!100);
color(75bp)=(pgftransparent!0); color(100bp)=(pgftransparent!0)}%

\pgfdeclarefading{south}{\pgfuseshading{pgf@lib@fade@south}}%
```

All I did was to change `color(25bp)=(pgftransparent!100);` to `color(40bp)=(pgftransparent!100);` in a fading I called `South` in

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{pgf@lib@fade@South}{100bp}
{color(0bp)=(pgftransparent!100); color(40bp)=(pgftransparent!100);
 color(75bp)=(pgftransparent!0); color(100bp)=(pgftransparent!0)}%
\pgfdeclarefading{South}{\pgfuseshading{pgf@lib@fade@South}}%
\makeatother
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
    paperwidth=17.78cm,
    paperheight=25.4cm,
    marginparsep=6.35mm,
    top=.5cm, % Top margin
    bottom=1cm, % Bottom margin
    left=2cm, % Left margin
    right=2cm, % Right margin
}

% Adds bleed
\usepackage[
width=18.0975cm,
height=26.035cm,
center,
%cam,
%cross,
%frame
]{crop}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \pagecolor{orange}\afterpage{\nopagecolor}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[overlay, white, line width=1.1mm] (-3,-.35) .. controls (-2.5,-4.5) and (5,-3.5) .. (20,.5);
        \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-6.15)},xscale=1,yscale=-1,rotate=360]
        \draw[overlay, white, line width=1.1mm,path fading=South] 
        (-3,-.35) .. controls (-2.5,-4.5) and (5,-3.5) .. (20,.5);  % Mirror Image
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `50bp` instead of `40bp` you get

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!