# Fade out of plot without affecting the grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-fadings

I'm trying to achieve a fade-out effect of my plot curve to the sides without affecting the grid. However, as I'm using `path fading` with white, the grid is also affected. Ideally this would be done by a separate command that I can just add after the plot like in my example, but any way to achieve the desired effect would be appreciated. A simple solution would be the use of `axis on top` with the fading inside the `axis` environment but I'd like to have the lines behind the fading plot.

MWE:
[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[thick,smooth,no markers,grid=both,axis x line=bottom,axis y line = left,]
        \addplot+[name path=A,blue!50] {sqrt(x)};
        \addplot+[name path=B,blue!50] {sqrt(x/2)};

        \addplot[blue!50,opacity=0.5] fill between[of=A and B];
    \end{axis}

 % fading
\fill [path fading=south,white]([yshift=0.1cm]current axis.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-0.5cm]current axis.north east);
\fill [path fading=west,white]  ([xshift=-1.5cm]current axis.south east) rectangle ([xshift=0.1cm]current axis.north east);    
% secondary axis so the x and y lines aren't faded (ideally not required)
 \begin{axis}[%
    grid=none,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line = left,
    minor tick num=0,
    xlabel=, 
    ylabel=,
    grid=none,
    ticks=none]%in m
\end{axis}   
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Nice question !

Comment: Thank you!  :-).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not know if it's possible to concot this into a *simple* style. One idea, after reading your comments, is:

- split the domain in one un-fading and other fading;
- apply the `east` fading (the fadings are only vertical or horizontal, I fear, so a north one is invisible on a narrow line)

like this:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        thick,smooth,no markers,grid=both,axis x line=bottom,axis y line = left,
        grid, domain=0.5:5
        ]
        \addplot+[domain=0.5:4,name path=A1, blue!50] {sqrt(x)};
        \addplot+[domain=0.5:4,name path=B1, blue!50] {sqrt(x/2)};
        \addplot[blue!50, opacity=0.5,] fill between[of=A1 and B1];
        %
        \addplot+[domain=4:5,name path=A,blue!50, path fading=east] {sqrt(x)};
        \addplot+[domain=4:5,name path=B,blue!50, path fading=east] {sqrt(x/2)};
        \addplot[blue!50, opacity=0.5,path fading=east] fill between[of=A and B];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Original answer (simple fading)

Hmmm... why two axis environments and the separate fading?

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}% <<<< don't forget this! (It's in the warnings!)
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        thick,smooth,no markers,grid=both,axis x line=bottom,axis y line = left,
        grid,
        ]
        \addplot+[name path=A,blue!50] {sqrt(x)};
        \addplot+[name path=B,blue!50] {sqrt(x/2)};
        \addplot[blue!50,opacity=0.5, path fading=north] fill between[of=A and B];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Can you update the solution so that the complete plot is affected by the fade to both corners over a small area like in the MWE? The fading outside of the plot is done as I have a document with multiple plots and I'd like to define (and change) the fading in one central definition and just add a command for each plot document. But I would accept an answer that fulfils the rest :-)

Comment: @Dwarfworld it is, although it's not easy to see (remove the opacity=0.5 to see it better). I am no expert on path fading option, you can try looking at https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#sec-15.9; let's see if someone else can add a better answer!

Comment: ...hmmm, really fadings are little documented... better look also at https://tikz.dev/base-shadings

Comment: I mean it doesn't fade in the x-direction and `path fading=north` doesn't seem to have any effect on the line plots when I add it to them. Unfortunately I ran into the same problems when I tried it with shading.

Comment: Thanks! I think I can work with the second example. Combining it with [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/545124/how-to-change-intensity-of-tikz-fading) answer, the fading can be set without the domain split. However, I can then use the domain split for examples where the plot starts from the top/ north and ends on the right/ east to have both, a vertical and horizontal fading.

Comment: There might be cases where this doesn't work (wide area in the top right corner), however [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180726/multiple-tikz-path-fading-in-multiple-directions) answer might help in that case. As I can work with your example I mark it as solved.

Comment: Very nice links, thanks.